# How to set X-Tick label size on Seaborn LineChart

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Running the code below produces a chart where the x-axis labels just get nuked.

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set() 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri") 
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", data=fmri) 
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xmajorticklabels(), fontsize = 12)
```

the same holds true for:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks())
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels())
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xmajorticklabels())
```

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: `ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=12)` as shown in the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of set_xtickslabels has to be a list of strings for it to work. Like such:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set() 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", data=fmri)  
ax.set_xticklabels([str(i) for i in ax.get_xticks()], fontsize = 20)
```

produces this output

[image]